# Prove $\def\rk{\operatorname{rank}}\rk{(A+B)}\leq \rk A+\rk B$ using only minors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A,B$ be two $(m,n)$ matrices. Prove that $$\def\rk{\operatorname{rank}}\rk{(A+B)}\leq \rk A+\rk B$$
using **only** the definition of $\rk$ involving non-zero minors.

I expressed every minor $\Delta_r$ of $A+B$ as a linear combination of minors of $A$ and $B$, each with order not less than $\lceil \frac{r}{2} \rceil$, but this approach didn't get me to the result.

I am a beginner in linear algebra and that is the only definition of $\rk$ I have learnt, so I would highly appreciate any solution using it.

**EDIT:** I think I managed to find a solution.
Let $A=(a_{ij}), B=(b_{ij})$ with $i\leq m$ and $j\leq n$. Also, $\rk A=r$ and $\rk B=s$. Then $A+B=(a_{ij}+b_{ij})$ and let $\Delta_{r+s+1}$ be a minor of $A+B$ of order $(r+s+1)$. Let $k=r+s+1$.
$$\Delta_{k}=\det \begin{pmatrix}
a_{i_1j_1}+b_{i_1j_1} & a_{i_1j_2}+b_{i_1j_2} &... &a_{i_1j_{k}}b_{i_1j_{k}} \\
...&...&...&...\\
a_{i_{k}j_1}+b_{i_{k}j_1}& a_{i_kj_2}+b_{i_kj_2}& ...& a_{i_kj_k}+b_{i_kj_k}\end{pmatrix}$$
Using the properties of determinants, we can develop the one above as a linear combination of determinants with the form
$$\det \begin{pmatrix}
a_{i_1p_1} & a_{i_1p_2}&... &a_{i_1p_{x}} & b_{i_1q_1} &b_{i_1q_2} &... &b_{i_1q_y} \\
a_{i_2p_1} & a_{i_2p_2}&... &a_{i_2p_{x}} & b_{i_2q_1} &b_{i_2q_2} &... &b_{i_2q_y} \\
...&...&...&...&...&...&...&...\\
a_{i_kp_1}& a_{i_kp_2}& ...& a_{i_kp_x} & b_{i_kq_1} & b_{i_kq_2} 
 & ... &b_{i_kq_y}\end{pmatrix}$$
where $x+y=k=r+s+1$ and $ \{ p_1,p_2,...p_x,q_1,q_2,...q_y \} = \{j_1,j_2,...j_k \}$

If $x \leq r$ then $y \geq s+1$ and we can write the last determinant as a linear combination of $(k-x)$order determinants consisting only of elements of  $B$. Since $k-x=y$, these will be minors of $B$ with order $y \geq s+1$ and since $\rk B=s$ it means that all these minors are $0$.

The same holds true if $x\geq r+1$, when we write the determinant as a linear combination of minors of $A$ with order $x$, thus all equal to $0$.

In conclusion, all the determinants with the form as above are $0$ and so $\Delta_k=0$, which means that $\rk(A+B) \leq r+s=\rk A+\rk B$

Comment: Can you express every minor $\Delta_{r+s+1}$ as a combination of $(r+1)$ minors of $A$ and $(s+1)$ minors of $B$? Maybe start with a simple case such as $m=n=3$, $r=s=1$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how. Can you provide further information, please?

Comment: It's clearly enough to prove that if $C$ and $D$ are two $m\times m$-matrices whose ranks (defined as the maximum sizes of nonzero minors) sum up to an integer $< m$, then $\det\left(C+D\right) = 0$. This follows from the messy formula for the determinant of a sum of two matrices in terms of minors of those matrices (e.g. Theorem 5.157 in [*Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, as of 25 May 2017](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2017-05-25)).

Comment: I think you used the Laplace expansion of a determinant wr to certain columns.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: It's the Romanian math manual for the 11th grade, authors: Marcel Tena, Marian Andronache, Dinu Serbanescu